# Why does adding mutable produce different hash values?

Tags: hash, julia, objectid

I have a simple `struct` like this with no custom `==` or `hash()` methods:

```
struct IntroductionMessage
    message::String
end
```

When I call `hash()` both return the same value:

```
say_hello_introduction = IntroductionMessage("Hello World")
say_hello_introduction_alternate = IntroductionMessage("Hello World")

hash(say_hello_introduction))
hash(say_hello_introduction_alternate))

# Output:
3650104434
3650104434
```

When I add the `mutable` keyword, so it's now `mutable struct IntroductionMessage`, the `hash()` values are different:

```
2957940122
238434212
```

The string itself never changed, so why does adding `mutable` produce a different result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default immutable `struct`s are hashed by value while `mutable struct`s are hashed by reference. This matches the default equality operations.